# Estimating the probability distribution of favorite movies

Tags: probability, statistics

Imagine that I repeat a random experiment in which I pick up someone in the population and ask his/her favorite movie : F

There exists about 300 000 movies but obviously F is not equi-probabilistic. Some movies have much more fans than others.

Now, imagine that I reproduce the random experiment N=1000 times and gather some $f_i$ ($1 \le i \le N$).
How could I estimate the number of movies that would represent R=80% of the weight of favorite movies ?

**My ideas to solve the problem :**

An important step would be to assess the family of distribution that F belongs to. Then to find the parameters of that distribution.

Intuitively, I would say that a geometric distribution is a good candidate. Well, geometric distribution is over an integer value while, in my case, it is over movies. But If I rank the movies from the most popular to the less popular, I can conceive a geometric distribution over the rank. You can also point that a geometric distribution has no limit while, in my case, the number of movies is finite but it is great. So geometric distribution could be a good approximation.

I have found how to find a max likelihood estimator of the parameter p of the geometric distribution. ([unbiased estimator for geometric distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/473190/unbiased-estimator-for-geometric-distribution))

So, my idea would be :

- ordering the movies in the samples set from the one that appears the more often in the $f_i$ to the one that appears the less.
- estimate the parameter p with $p=\dfrac{n}{n+\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-1)}$ (where $X_i$ is the rank of $f_i$).
- use the geometric distribution CDF : $1-(1-p)^k$ to get the k that represent s 0.8

What do you think of my idea ?

Comment: I've made a compensatory upvote for the sake of your effort.  But your question is sort of unclear.  On one hand, you seem to be asking what *kind* of distribution "favorite movie" is likely to have.  (An excellent question!). But on the other hand, you then seem to *assume* that the geometric distribution is likely (I think a power law is at least as plausible), and then want to know what parameter is most likely. Can you say how this question arose and how you plan to use/interpret the answer?

Comment: I have changed the question to reflect my final aim : estimate the number of movie that represent a certain percentage of the weight. finding a distribution family is part of the strategy to answer that question. The context is a game where an IA find a movie the user is thinking of by asking questions. So far , we have few played games and wonder how many movies would represent 80% of the games.